# How to return plain values from bluebird promises?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am new to promises.
I am using Bluebird promises for running an async function in this fashion.

```
var contract_creation = function creation(contractName){
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject){

        web3.eth.sendTransaction(
            {
                from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
                data:contractsJSON[contractName].bytecode,
                gas:gasprice

            },
            function(err, transactionHash){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    resolve(transactionHash);
                }
            }
        );
    });

}

var getCreatedContract = function getReceipt(name){
    contract_creation(name)
    .then(function(transactionHash){
        return web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);
    });
}

getCreatedContract("Fund").then(function(receipt){
    console.log(receipt);
});
```

sendTransaction is an async operation which takes time.

After running this I am getting this exception.

```
getCreatedContract("Fund").then(function(receipt){
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Can't I return something from .then() and that would also be a promise. What is the correct way of returning values from promise functions ?

Comment: Yes you can, but you must not forget to `return` the new promise from your actual function

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed return a Promise within a `then` to pass execution to another asynchronous operation...

Whenever you want to do this, you must return the Promise. Here, that means returning the Promise that is created within `getCreatedContract`:

```
var getCreatedContract = function getReceipt(name){
    return contract_creation(name)
//  ^^^^^^
        .then(function(transactionHash){
            return web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Actually I am not very sure whether I wrote the caption of this question correctly ie "How to return plain values from bluebird promises". Can you suggest a good caption so future users might benefit from it ?

Answer (score 1):

*sdgluck* gave you the answer but you can improve your code a bit more, you're using Bluebird so you can promisify `sendTransaction()`:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var contract_creation = function creation(contractName) {
    // if you need this promisified function elsewhere, you can declare it globally
    var sendTransactionAsync = Promise.promisify(web3.eth.sendTransaction);

    return sendTransactionAsync({
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
        data: contractsJSON[contractName].bytecode,
        gas: gasprice
    });
}

var getCreatedContract = function getReceipt(name) {
    return contract_creation(name)
        .then(web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt); // << no need to wrap the function inside another function
}

getCreatedContract("Fund").then(function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
});
```

Comment: There might be a need to wrap them (or at least bind them) if they're methods

Comment: @ShanShan In sendTransactionAsync where will I do a resolve or reject the transactionHash. I did not get you.

Comment: @codestruggle That's `promisify()`'s job, it will handle resolve/reject for you.  The [doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) for detailed explanations.

Comment: @ShanShan It took sometime for me to understand. But your solution works as well. Very good upvoting. So for those of you who did not understand his solution the sendTransaction function has to conform to the nodejs sunction format for callbacks i.e first value as error and second value as the actual expected value and Bluebird will automatically resolve that value for you and you dont have to do it manually like I did in the question. very important.

Comment: @ShanShan I wanted to know that instead of a promise can I get directly the receipt object that I am looking for somehow.

Comment: @codestruggle No, that's the thing with async call, you can't have the result directly, you can get back a promise or you can pass a callback, there is no shortcut yet ([async/await keywords](http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html) are coming with ES7, you can already use them with BabelJS).